# map.resources with alternate primary key(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a Rails model `Object` that does not have an ID column. It instead uses a tuple of primary keys from two other models as its primary key, `dependency_id` and `user_id`.

What I want to do is be able to do something like this in `routes.rb`:

```
map.resources :object, :primary_key => [:dependency_id, :user_id]
```

And for it to magically generate URLs like this:

```
/objects/:dependency_id/:user_id
/objects/:dependency_id/:user_id/1
/objects/:dependency_id/:user_id/1/edit
```

...Except that I just made that up, and there is no such syntax.

Is there a way to customize `map.resources` so I can get the RESTful URLs, without having to make custom routes for everything? Or am I just screwed for not following the ID convention?

The `:path_prefix` option looks somewhat promising, however I would still need a way to remove the `id` part of the URL. And I'd like to still be able to use the path helpers if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `Object` model's method `to_param` to reflect your primary key. Something like this:

```
def to_param
  [dependency_id, user_id].join('-')
end
```

Then when you'll be setting urls for these objects (like `object_path(some_object)`) it will automatically gets converted to something like `/objects/5-3`. Then in show action you'd have to split the `params[:id]` on dash and find object by dependency_id and user_id:

```
def show
  dep_id, u_id = params[:id].split('-').collect(&:to_i)
  object = Object.find_by_dependency_id_and_user_id(dep_id, u_id)
end
```

You can also look at [`find_by_param` gem for rails](http://github.com/bumi/find_by_param).

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll give it a go.

Comment: This works great. It's unfortunate that '/' is not a usable separator, but a dash isn't bad either. Thanks for the help!